# Problem with assign df$COLUMN[x] = df2$COLUMN[y] in R

Tags: r

A few months ago I made a little loop to assign automatically the columns of two data frames. Basically, df contains only "Depth" values, and df2 contains both "Depth" and "Age" values. So when the "Depth" values are equal I can assign the "Age" values to df.

```
i = 1
k = 1
while (k < length(df2$Depth)) {
  if (df2$Depth[k] == df$Depth[i]){
    df$Age2[i] = df2$Age[k]
    i = i + 1
  }
  k = k + 1
}
```

Recently I needed to use this loop again but I found out that it isn't woking anymore, and it's not because of the loop... Anytime I want to assign the values of a colunm by `df$COLUNM[x] = df2$COLUNM[y]` it doesn't work. The value that are assign for `df$COLUNM[x]` instead of the true value `df2$COLUNM[y]` is the row number relative to their position.

Just don't know if it's a bug or something that I'm doing wrong... Don't get it why this was working till few months ago and now it isn't.

Comment: could you add a `dput()` of `df2` and `df` ? if its too big, at least a `dput(head())`

Comment: Ooh, when I read your comment I instantly remember that I forgot to check the class of my colunms... Now I already set all of them to numbers and it's working perfectly. Thank you, sorry for the dumb mistake :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way (and the only way I can think of) for this to happen is that you  inadvertently created a factor variable that looks like it is numeric and then assign values to a "true" numeric. See this example:

```
X <- rnorm(10)
y=factor(1:10)
y=factor(101:110)
X[4] <- y[5]
X
 [1] -0.2093544 -1.8858439 -0.1048452  5.0000000 -1.1665309
 [6] -2.1416764  1.6572388 -0.7806782  1.0002025  0.6032613
```

Notice that the "value" of y[5] was not "accepted" by X, but rather its relative position in the levels of the factor was assigned. So you should  check:

```
class(df2$Age)
```

My strong suspicion is that the result will be "factor". And you can recover the original values with:

```
df2$Age <- as.numeric(as.character(df2$Age))
```

Comment: You're right! I forgot to check the class of my variables... It was a factor indeed. Thank you :)